# The superclass "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" was not found on the Java Build Path - common fix doesn't work

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to create a dynamic web project on Eclipse and this is the error I receive every time I make a project.  I have a Tomcat v10.0 server created that it should be using.  I have tried going to project Properties Project Facets Runtimes and Targeted Runtimes and both locations have my Tomcat server checked.  I have also tried putting the servlet jar directly into WEB-INF/lib but this did not work either. Thoughts on what might fix this?

Comment: Please read http://tomcat.apache.org/migration-10.html carefully.  Note that the package for the servlet classes has changed, and you will need to modify any of your code that depends on this from `javax.servlet.*` to `jakarta.servlet.*`.  Alternatively, consider using the migration tool ...

Comment: Or use Tomcat 9 instead.